# How to parse a TAB TYPE OUT from a oracle procedure using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, procedure, cx-oracle

DATABASE (ORACLE):

```
Create or replace TYPE xyz.OUTPUT_TYPE_TAB is TABLE OF OUTPUT_TYP
```

```
Create or replace TYPE OUTPUT_TYP IS OBJECT(A VARCHAR(20),B VARCHAR(20), dt TIMESTAMP(6))
```

```
Create or replace procedure XYZ_PROC(IN_DT IN DATEtab_out OUT OUTPUT_TYPE_TAB) ASBEGINTab_out := OUTPUT_TYPE_TAB();Select OUTPUT_TY(A,B,dt) BULK COLLECT INTO TABLE_TYPE from tab_x where .... ;END XYZ_PROC;
```

Python :

```
Def get_impl()
     #do connection initialization
     Connection = get_conn(); #getting a cx_oracle connection pool
     Cur = connection.cursor()
     Obj_type=connection.gettype("OUTPUT_TYPE_TAB")
     Out_obj=obj_type.newobject()
     S="BEGIN XYZ_PROC(:1,:2)"
     Cur.execute(S,['ABC',Out_obj])
     #how do I parse the result from Out_obj ?
```

So the above is the proc and the DB objects which I have and the code snippet from python, if I want to read the result of the select from the proc into my python how Mac I parse it. Please advice.

I know embedding the SQL itself I can parse the cursor results , but wanted to now how an DB TYPE object can be parsed as output.

I have tried printing the output object but no luck I tried printing the cursor, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to get an output object. Note I am using python-oracledb (the successor to cx_Oracle) but this should work just as well with cx_Oracle.

```py
import datetime

import oracledb

conn = oracledb.connect("user/password@localhost/service_name")
cursor = conn.cursor()
var = cursor.var(typ=conn.gettype("OUTPUT_TYPE_TAB"))
cursor.callproc("xyz_proc", [datetime.datetime.today(), var])
print("value:", var.getvalue())
```

Comment: For general object types, the object_dump.py example https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/object_dump.py may be helpful